# How many WAL logs are created on a large DELETE or BATCH statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, wal

Let's say I do a `DELETE FROM table WHERE table.a = 5` and that accounts for 10 million records. Will that create 10M entries in the WAL or will that just be a single entry?

Answer (score 0):

WAL is a record of physical changes to the blocks of data on disk. So if your 10 million records are scattered across 2 million blocks that is how much WAL will be generated. In general you would want to also consider and index updates a query might cause. The vacuum process can also generate substantial WAL data.

Comment: When I run `pg_waldump` with `-f`(follow) I see individual commands for each `DELETE` being applied to the appropriate block. If done in a `BEGIN;` there is also additional record keeping statements. Also the `VACUUM` housekeeping.

Answer (score 0):

You will get one WAL record per row. The first time a page it modified after a checkpoint you will get a full page image (FPI) in the WAL, after that only the modified `xmax` value will be logged.